# How can I tell if an Oracle Package is natively compiled?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have some packages installed in Oracle, and I would like to see if they are natively compiled. Is there a way to check this in the data dictionary?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check if a package has been natively compiled using the dictionary views:

Oracle 9i:

`USER_STORED_SETTINGS`, `DBA_STORED_SETTINGS` and `ALL_STORED_SETTINGS`.

For example:

```
SELECT param_value 
  FROM user_stored_settings 
 WHERE param_name = 'PLSQL_COMPILER_FLAGS'
   AND object_name = 'MY_PACKAGE';
```

The `PARAM_VALUE` column has a value of `NATIVE` for procedures that are compiled for native execution, and `INTERPRETED` otherwise.

Oracle 10g and 11g:

`USER_PLSQL_OBJECT_SETTINGS`, `DBA_PLSQL_OBJECT_SETTINGS` and `ALL_PLSQL_OBJECT_SETTINGS`
see the `PLSQL_CODE_TYPE` column.

See: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_compiled_pl_sql.htm and http://www.pastusiak.info/oracle/native_compilation for more information.

Hope it helps...

Comment: That's great thank you. Unfortunately it means I can't get a massive speed-up by natively compiling as my packages already are :-)

Comment: In my case the param_name are in lowercase, so had to change where first condition to:
 WHERE UPPER(param_name) = 'PLSQL_COMPILER_FLAGS'